# Updating Ubuntu packages fails to fetch

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I'm trying to get my ubuntu(14.04LTS) updated, and I failed with this message:

W: Failed to fetch [this](http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release)  Unable to find expected entry `'main/binary-1386/Packages'` in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

I'm quite sure this should be i386, not 1386, but I have no idea how to fix this ridiculous error.

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: which version you wants to update your ubuntu...

Comment: I was just trying to have my ubuntu's softwares up-to-date, so I tried sudo apt-get update, not targeting specific version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the arch file located here:

```
vi /var/lib/dpkg/arch
```

There will be an entry 1386, it should either be removed or changed to i386 depending on the architecture of your system and the other entries within the file.

Comment: I tried what you said, tried several servers, but all of them failed with same error message I mentioned on question.

Comment: I would try the manual update of the sources.list file. Make sure it's a lower case i

Sorry I edited my answer a couple of times.

Comment: I attempted to do that way at the first time, but I only saw the URL of the server, without any source or directory name in the file. Where can I find the list of it?

Comment: I believe it should be directly on the sources.list file, sorry I don't have an Ubuntu instance up at the moment. Can you post the contents of yours in pastebin or gist?

Comment: You mean the contents of the sources.list file?

Comment: Yes the contents of your sources.list file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97043/discussion-between-dan-king-and-junyeon-julian-weon).